# Confused about functional languages

Tags: ruby, scala, haskell, functional-programming

I have been developing in object oriented languages for over 10 years now (both C# and java). But more and more I hear a lot of people talking about functional programming languages: Ruby, Scala, Haskell, ...

And while I have read a lot about these programming languages. Unfortunately, **most tutorials spend most of their time talking about syntax.** But I haven't found any tutorials that explains the domains or **any turorials that give a typical practical application of these languages.**

I am stuck with a lot of questions, here follows a short list of simple questions that go on in my mind.

**Are they standalone languages?**

- Are functional languages to be used from within another programming languages. The same way as Java/C# use other languages such as SQL, Regex, HQL, XQL, ... ?
- If used standalone, do they use compilers ?

**How powerful are their frameworks ?**

- Is there support for graphical components such as windows or dialogs ?
- Is there support for multi-threading ?
- Is there support for socket interaction, webservices ?

**Summary:** Can somebody quickly answer the questions that I mentioned, or maybe even better, can you provide me some links to tutorials with **practical** examples ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: simplified/ removed some questions

Comment: Not an answer by itself, but I heartily recommend you to read [this classic paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html)

Comment: I've thought of a better way to think about this question.  Or perhaps it's just a way I think will better explain why I find your questions to be the wrong ones.  Go through your question and replace "functional" with "assembly" then read the question.  "Functional languages" is a class of languages that transcend syntax, application area, execution mechanism, or runtime features.

Comment: Made some changes to the question, in response to the "on hold" request of several people. Better?

Comment: Hi @bvdb your asking a personal question (could someone explain ME FP on these points:...) unfortunately. As you see such questions are not welcome here. I suggest you go to the #haskell or #scalaz IRC channels on freenode, there are helpful people which will answer YOUR questions. Besides that. Here is a nice introduction video also answering your questions on IO with FP: http://vimeo.com/m/18554216

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, I don't see why this topic is more "personal" than for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460042/data-processing-how-to-approach . Your comments to my question is extremely subjective. While indeed several people downvoted this question, also several people upvoted this question. So, at least that shows that there are other people who wonders about this question too. Then how can it be a "personal" question? Anyway, isn't it a bit offensive to write that somebody's questions are "not welcome"? Surely your comments is more personal than the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Are functional languages to be called from within another programming languages. The same way as Java/C# use other languages such as SQL, Regex, HQL, XQL, ... ?

They can be, but needn't be limited to such a convention.

> Can a functional language use a framework like the java framework or .net framework ? If so, do these frameworks use graphical components such as windows or dialogs ?

Yes - F# is a good example here.

> Can a functional language only be used for console applications and websites that simply echo output to some kind of stream ?

No.

> Can a functional language be used standalone. If so, do they use compilers ?

Yes, they can be standalone.  Yes, they can use a compiler - these are just languages - the manner of execution is entirely up to the implementer.  There are interpreters and compilers for many functional languages.

> I use java for multithreaded client-server applications with a front-end that acts as a desktop application (thick client). Could I replace all my java code by code written in a functional language?

You can write mutlithreaded programs in functional languages, you can write desktop applications, and you can implement any arbitrary algorithm in one of these languages just like you have in Java.  Are you trying to ask something more particular with this question?

> Are functional languages a subcategory of the procedural languages ?

No.

> Is it just a matter of syntax or is there more to it ?

More to it.  I'd say that a functional language is one that encourages you to program in a functional style.  This is far-afield of the focus of Stack Overflow.  I suggest you see pre-existing material on the subject, such as the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_programming).